# Purpose of localConnector-1.0 feature in Websphere server with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere, websphere-liberty

I was following a tutorial for setting up a WebSphere Liberty Server [Here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-apps-with-intellij-idea-and-liberty-profile/) and didn't really know what a part of the tutorial did. I completed the tutorial and it works fine.

On step 3 it has me modify the server.xml with these two lines and I dont really know what they do.

```
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

<feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
```

I Found the documentation for localConnector-1.0 but its a little over my head
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_localConnector-1.0.html

I think localConnector allows IntelliJ to run the server somehow but i dont know what updateTrigger="mbean" does.

If anyone has an explanation that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localConnector-1.0 feature enables the local JMX connector on Liberty so that the JMX Client (IntelliJ) can connect to and administer Liberty.
You can find more documentation on the feature here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_localconnector.html

updateTrigger="mbean" is setting the application updates to only occur when trigger by an mbean call (whereas the default is to poll for changes).
You can find more documentation here: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_setup_dyn_upd.html